# locations read from CSV file using java and locate them into google maps

Tags: java

I am facing a problem in finding a way using java through which I can locate location points(Lat,Long) from large CSV file to google map.

I was able to read the locations data from the big dataset but I face a problem in placing the points in streaming way to google maps.

I am not expert in programming but I started with below code:

```
    JFrame test = new JFrame("Google Maps");

    try {

        String latitude = "45.714728";

        String longitude = "-73.998672";

        String imageUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+ latitude+ ","+ longitude+ "&zoom=11&size=612x612&scale=2&maptype=roadmap";

        String destinationFile = "image.jpg";

        // read the map image from Google

        // then save it to a local file: image.jpg


        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);

        InputStream is = url.openStream();

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];

        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {

            os.write(b, 0, length);

        }

        is.close();
        os.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
        }

    // create a GUI component that loads the image: image.jpg
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon((new ImageIcon("image.jpg"))

            .getImage().getScaledInstance(630, 600,

                    java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

    test.add(new JLabel(imageIcon));

    // show the GUI window

    test.setVisible(true);

    test.pack();
```

appreciated any help,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [mcve]. You show some code - but it is not clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: In the code I provided the points (Lat,Long) are written, what I want is to make this variable so that I read every line from the dataset and get the location on the map and keep doing it till I end up with points for all locations I read from the dataset file

Comment: I need to make the following code to be dynamic insted of statistic where it takes values written within code.

Comment: String latitude = "45.714728";

   String longitude = "-73.998672";

   String imageUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+ latitude+ ","+ longitude+ "&zoom=11&size=612x612&scale=2&maptype=roadmap";

Answer (score 1):

The dataset being huge, as you have mentioned, you shouldn't be going for URL based solution. URL has a character limit and hence beyond a point your solution won't work. You should look for some api to get you plotted locations. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple).

If the number of points you want to plot is relatively less you can use following approach.

```
String center = centerLat + "," + centerLong;
String points[] = {lat1+","+long1, lat2+","+long2};//points from csv
String plottedPoints = new String();
for(String point: points) {
    plottedPoints = plottedPoints + point + "|";
}
//Finally construct the url
String imageUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + center + "&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers="+plottedPoints;
```

And then read the resulting image as you have already done.

Comment: I will try this and come back to provide feedback.

Comment: It works perfectly, However I went to the link you provided me as the data is really huge. The code is written using JavaScript however I want to use the result file from my java code. There is no way to communicate between java and JavaScript?